# Wordpress insert row in MySQL table at same time setcookie() is run?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to insert the information from a cookie that is stored from a user login in a custom MySQL table in Wordpress. The site I'm working on has a separate app (R Shiny) that needs authenticate users based on the cookie with a key, and I'm hoping to store the authentication information in MySQL to be accessed from this app. This app is quite limited in what it can access from the site, but pulling data from a SQL table is the most robust way I've found to do this. Here is what the code in functions.php looks like, but a bit simpler/more basic:

```
add_action('init', 'custom_set_login_cookie'); 
function custom_set_login_cookie() {

    if ( is_user_logged_in()  && !isset($_COOKIE['custom_cookie'])) { 
        
        // Get cookie string proprties 
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $name_current = $current_user->user_login; 
        
        // Set random key for authentication 
        $auth_key = bin2hex(random_bytes(10));
        $cookie_str = $name_current . ' ' . $auth_key; 

        // Set cookie
        setcookie('custom_cookie', $cookie_str, time()+300, '/'); 

        // Insert row to DB for later authentication 
        global $wpdb; 

        $wpdb->insert('custom_table', array(
            'user_name' => $name_current,
            'key' => $auth_key
            )   
        );
    }
}
```

This works for the most part (there is a corresponding function that removes this row at logout). The cookie is set, the row is inserted into the custom table in the DB. However, I'm running into issues with this function inserting rows at random times when it shouldn't. For instance, if the page has been loaded for a bit (say 20 minutes) and an action is performed (say when a user tries to logout) without a new refresh, often a new row is added to the DB when it shouldn't be since the cookie is already set.

Is there a way to ensure the MySQL insert portion is run exactly when `setcookie` is run? Is there another conditional I should add to the if statement to ensure the insert is only run if the cookie is newly set? Should I hook the MySQL insert portion (or possibly both the `setcookie` and insert portion) to a different action than 'inti'? Is there a better way to do this overall? Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: You mean the same data is inserted (user_name , key) into the custom_table MORE THAN ONCE ?

Comment: Kind of. The "key" is different though, so I know that the `random_bytes` bit is being run again, but the setcookie is not. The custom table has additional columns that I didn't include here, one of which is a unique identifier that is the primary key in the SQL table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it took me a while, but after much testing it appears the way I was able to get this to work was to rely on setting php session variables. I had to create 4 separate functions: 1.) start session, 2.) `setcookie` and write the required `$_SESSION` variables, 3.) check that everything set up correctly and write the variables to the MySQL db and then remove the variables and 4.) remove the cookie and corresponding authentication row in the db at logout. I also set the first three functions to have late priority in 1/2/3 order.

I apologize for the lack of code, but it ended up being quite specific to my site, and to be honest a long process (a lot of code), so not really suitable in an answer. If anyone has any question please feel free to reply and I'll try to answer. To close this I am going to accept my answer.